# Hibernate Validator 5.2.3 Spring Form Validation Error: java.lang.AbstractMethodError

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

**servlet-context.xml**

```
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.app">
        <context:exclude-filter type="regex" expression="com\.test.*"/>
    </context:component-scan>
```

**/web/WEB-INF/lib:**

```
hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar
hibernate-core-5.0.7.Final.jar
hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.7.Final.jar
hibernate-validator-5.2.3.Final.jar
validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar
classmate-1.1.0.jar
```

**WebLogic 10.3.6 setDomainEnv.cmd**

```
set MW_MODULE=C:\oracle\MIDDLEWARE\modules

set PRE_CLASSPATH=%MW_MODULE%\hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar;%MW_MODULE%\hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar;%MW_MODULE%\hibernate-core-5.0.7.Final.jar;%MW_MODULE%\hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.7.Final.jar;%MW_MODULE%\hibernate-validator-5.2.3.Final.jar;%MW_MODULE%\validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar;%MW_MODULE%\classmate-1.1.0.jar;%PRE_CLASSPATH%
```

**weblogic.xml**

```
<wls:container-descriptor>
        <wls:prefer-application-packages>
            <wls:package-name>java.persistence.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.hibernate.validator.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>javax.validator.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>javassist.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:package-name>
            <wls:package-name>org.apache.logging.log4j.*</wls:package-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-packages>

        <wls:prefer-application-resources>
            <wls:resource-name>java.persistence.*</wls:resource-name>
            <wls:resource-name>org.hibernate.*</wls:resource-name>
            <wls:resource-name>org.hibernate.validator.*</wls:resource-name>
            <wls:resource-name>javax.validator.*</wls:resource-name>
            <wls:resource-name>javassist.*</wls:resource-name>
            <wls:resource-name>org.slf4j.*</wls:resource-name>
            <wls:resource-name>org.apache.logging.log4j.*</wls:resource-name>
        </wls:prefer-application-resources>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
```

**Stack Trace:**

```
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
    at javax.persistence.Persistence$1.isLoaded(Persistence.java:111) ~[hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:46) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.3.Final.jar:5.2.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:128) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.3.Final.jar:5.2.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.isReachable(CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.java:36) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.3.Final.jar:5.2.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isReachable(ValidatorImpl.java:1522) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.3.Final.jar:5.2.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:1507) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.3.Final.jar:5.2.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:584) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.3.Final.jar:5.2.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:555) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.3.Final.jar:5.2.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:490) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.3.Final.jar:5.2.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:454) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.3.Final.jar:5.2.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:406) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.3.Final.jar:5.2.3.Final]
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:204) ~[hibernate-validator-5.2.3.Final.jar:5.2.3.Final]
    at com.app.controller.SomeController.retrievePage(SomeController.java:68) ~[_wl_cls_gen.jar:?]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[?:1.7.0_75]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:222) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137) ~[spring-web-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:814) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:737) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
```

**SomeController.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/retrieve", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String retrievePage(@ModelAttribute("someForm")SomeForm form, BindingResult result) {
        Set<ConstraintViolation<SomeForm>> violations = validator.validate(form);

        for (ConstraintViolation<DealRetrieveForm> constraintViolation : violations) {
            result.addError(new FieldError("someForm", constraintViolation.getPropertyPath().toString(), constraintViolation.getMessage()));
        }

        if(result.hasErrors()){
            return "home";
        }

        return "retrieve";
    }
```

I have spent the past 2 days searching the internet to find anything I can to help correct this error, but nothing has worked.